# AttributeError: 'SimpleCache' object has no attribute 'has'

Tags: python, werkzeug

I get the following error from this code:

```
def render(template, **kw):    
    if not cache.has("galleries"):
        cache.set('galleries', getTable(Gallery))
    return render_template(template, galleries=galleries, **kw)
```

Error:

```
File "/vagrant/diane/diane.py", line 38, in render
if cache.has("galleries"):
AttributeError: 'SimpleCache' object has no attribute 'has'
```

I have used the same code several times before without any issue. I also copied this and ran a simple test and it works

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache
cache = SimpleCache()

def x():
    if cache.has('y'):
        print 'yes'
        print cache.get("y")
    else:
       print 'no'
x()
```

Any ideas at all would be really appreciated.

Comment: Docs say "This method is optional and may not be implemented on all caches." does that apply to the instance of SimpleCache being used in diane.py ? http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/contrib/cache/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comment of @JacobIRR, from doc it is clear that its a optional field.

The docs says as follows:

> has(key) Checks if a key exists in the cache without returning it.
>   This is a cheap operation that bypasses loading the actual data on the
>   backend.
>
> This method is optional and may not be implemented on all caches.
>
> Parameters:   key – the key to check

Here to avoid this we can use `get(key)` method

> get(key) Look up key in the cache and return the value for it.
>
> Parameters:   key – the key to be looked up. Returns: The value if it
>   exists and is readable, else None.
>       from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache
>       cache = SimpleCache()

Here is what we can do by using `get(key)`:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import SimpleCache
cache = SimpleCache()

def x():
    if cache.get("y"): # if 'y' is not present it will return None.
        print 'yes'
    else:
       print 'no'
x()
```